# MuPDF: clickListener on hyperlinks

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

I use mupdf to view pdf files. 
I built Android project using [this instructions](http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android)

However I can't click on the link in the text, e.x. url (it's highlighted but viewer doesn't react on click)

How could I jump through link in pdf file when click on it?

I'm also interested in alternative free pdf libraries for Android that supports hyperlinks.

Comment: *url (it's highlighted but viewer doesn't react on click)* - probably the PDF merely contains information to show the URL in a highlighted way but not that it is a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a similar feature in our Android customizable magazine app, using muPDF: it is possible to "tap" on the links in the text, either external links, or links to other pages.
This app is open source and available on [Github](https://github.com/libreliodev/android). It should be easy for you to review the code, and see how we implemented this feature.

Comment: Hi librelio, I tried this sample.Internal links are working .But external links(hyperlinks) are not working.What may be reason?do u have any suggestion?

Comment: @user2894326 We have many apps in production with external links working perfectly, so there is no reason for this. Feel free to post an issue on Github explaining the problem in details

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The pdf that i tested have some problem. It works fine in other pdfs.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
"https://github.com/libreliodev/android" this link provides you pdf library which suppourts hyperlinks but it has lot other stuff, 
what you need to do is after downloading the zip from the link extract it and load it in eclipse  

1) create a activity and declare it in manifest 
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity /** base activity is available in library itself **/


{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MuPDFActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        resultIntent.setData(Uri.parse("give the path of your pdf location"));
        resultIntent.putExtra(Magazine.FIELD_TITLE, "Title");
        startActivity(resultIntent);
    }

}
it will load the pdf
```